# Delphi 6 to Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-6

Just hitting various bricks walls with years worth of code updating, but the current one i cant seem to convert is this

```
Function Pack (Var Source, Dest; Count : Word) : Word; Assembler;
Asm
  Push  DS
  Mov   BX, Count                               { BX = Count }
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest
  Mov   DI, AX
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest+2           `1`
  Mov   ES, AX                                  { ES:DI - Dest }
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Source
  Mov   SI, AX
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Source+2
  Mov   DS, AX                                  { DS:SI - Source }
  Xor   DX, DX                                  { Packed size }
  CLD
@Cycle:
  Or    BX, BX
  JZ    @End                                    { Done }
  LODSB
  Mov   CX, BX
  Cmp   CX, 100H
  JC    @1
  Mov   CX, 0FFH
@1:
  Mov   AH, CL
  Push  ES
  Push  DI                                      { Save ES:DI before scan }
  Push  SI
  Pop   DI
  Push  DS
  Pop   ES                                      { ES:DI = DS:SI for scan }
  RepE  ScaSB
  Dec   DI
  Push  DI
  Pop   SI
  Push  ES
  Pop   DS                                      { DS:SI = ES:DI for next }
  Pop   DI
  Pop   ES                                      { Restore ES:DI after scan }
  Sub   AH, CL
  Mov   CL, AH                                  { CX = repeat count }
  Cmp   AH, 3
  JNC   @3                                      { Repeat count >= 3 }
  Cmp   AL, RP
  JNE   @2                                      { Not a RepeatPrefix byte }
  STOSW                                         { Save RP, repeat count < 3 }
  Sub   BX, CX                                  { Actually count in source }
  Add   DX, 2                                   { Actually packed size }
  Jmp   @Cycle
@2:
  Sub   BX, CX                                  { Actually count in source }
  Add   DX, CX                                  { Actually packed size }
  Rep   STOSB                                   { Save bytes }
  Jmp   @Cycle
@3:
  Sub   BX, CX                                  { Actually count in source }
  Add   DX, 3                                   { Actually packed size }
  Mov   CL, AL
  Mov   AL, RP
  STOSW                                         { Save RP, repeat count < 3 }
  Mov   AL, CL
  STOSB                                         { Save repeating byte }
  Jmp   @Cycle
@End:
  Pop   DS
  Mov   AX, DX                                  { Return packed size }
End;

Function UnPack (Var Source, Dest; Count : Word) : Word; Assembler;
Asm
  Push  DS
  Mov   BX, Count                               { BX = Count }
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest
  Mov   DI, AX
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest+2
  Mov   ES, AX                                  { ES:DI - Dest }
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Source
  Mov   SI, AX
  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Source+2
  Mov   DS, AX                                  { DS:SI - Source }
  Xor   DX, DX                                  { Packed size }
  Xor   AH, AH
  CLD
@Cycle:
  Or    BX, BX
  JZ    @End                                    { Done }
  LODSB
  Dec   BX
  Cmp   AL, RP
  JE    @1
  STOSB
  Inc   DX
  Jmp   @Cycle
@1:
  LODSB
  Mov   CX, AX
  Add   DX, CX
  Dec   BX
  Cmp   AL, 3
  JNC   @2
  Mov   AL, RP
  Rep   STOSB
  Jmp   @Cycle
@2:
  LODSB
  Dec   BX
  Rep   STOSB
  Jmp   @Cycle
@End:
  Pop   DS
  Mov   AX, DX
End;
```

```
[DCC Error] Packer.pas(20): E2107 Operand size mismatch  "  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest"
[DCC Error] Packer.pas(22): E2105 Inline assembler syntax error"  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest+2           `1`"
[DCC Error] Packer.pas(24): E2107 Operand size mismatch "Mov   AX, Word Ptr Source"
[DCC Error] Packer.pas(87): E2107 Operand size mismatch"  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Dest"
[DCC Error] Packer.pas(91): E2107 Operand size mismatch "  Mov   AX, Word Ptr Source"
```

I spent far to many years on d6, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't compile in Delphi 6 either. Please post the code that does compile in Delphi 6. What you really should be doing is getting rid of asm that you cannot understand. Write your program using Pascal and let the compiler do the rest. Delphi 6 -> Delphi 2007 is a rather odd upgrade. I can't see what you would choose to do that now.

Comment: It's company into new hands and wants modernising I never had to recompile dcu since I joined the company so took it as the pas is fine.  Will take my first action back there cheers for heads up

Comment: Seems more like Turbo Pascal assembly.

Comment: @David - If I remember correctly there is no date for Delphi2007 to go (totally) unsupported.  It may be that the OP's company policy requires it, however bonkers it may be.

Comment: @LURD, not a specific TP, but general 16-bit.

Comment: @David D6 -> D2007 isn't that weird. It's an upgrade to the latest pre-unicode version. Switching to unicode brings its own set of complications; more so in applications that need to adhere to communication protocols with external systems. In our case we've used D2007 as a stepping stone towards newer versions.

Comment: @CraigYoung I don't really see what you get in way of a stepping stone. It's not any easier to get to Unicode Delphi from D2007 than it is from D6.

Comment: @David I agree the work has to be done regardless; and doing the work later doesn't decrease the amount of work required. However, in our case, the additional Unicode work is a large amount of work. (Partly because of legacy mistakes such as injudicious use of `AnsiString`s in an inconsistent way.) The fact remains, paying of technical debt has to be balanced with the business need to continuously add functionality. If I had the luxury of a month/two to convert to Unicode unimpeded, I'd gladly do so. Currently D2007 changes are done. I can work on fixing legacy mistakes and use D2007 features.

Comment: @CraigYoung I guess it's different for everyone, but my experience was that stepping via D2007 would have involved more work than going straight from D6 to D2010, as we did.

Comment: Yeah, I no longer recommend D2007 as an interim step in upgrading, it's too darn buggy.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, inline assembly code that compiles in Delphi 6 will compile in later versions too. So no porting should be needed. Indeed, when you attempt to compile this code in Delphi 6, it fails with exactly the same errors as you report from D2007.

You also mention in the comments that you have not been compiling the code in Delphi 6, but have rather been using a compiled .dcu file. Which makes more sense, given that the code in the question does not compile in Delphi 6.

The reason the code does not compile in Delphi 6 is that it is not 32 bit code. It seems to me to be 16 bit code.

Reading between the lines I suspect that the code you have dates from long ago, in the 16 bit age. When the code was moved to 32 bit someone ported the code but left you a .dcu file rather than the source.

You are thus in a pickle. Without knowing what's in this .dcu file what are you to do? Are you even sure that the .dcu file does the same as this 16 bit assembly code? Do you have a functional specification for these functions?

In an ideal world you would know what these functions do and would be able to port them to Pascal. Then you would no longer be tied to assembler code.

If you don't know what these functions do you should find out. I would not trust that your 16 bit assembler matches what your .dcu file does. I would disassemble the .dcu file and port that to Pascal.

If even that's too hard, then the expedient approach is to use Delphi 6 to compile the .dcu file into a DLL. Then you can call these functions from your ported D20007 program. This will work but it leaves you no closer to knowing what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is 16 bit register.

[image]

Just an idea, maybe declare in your variables example AX as word and AH, AL as byte but you will need to rename them.

example...

```
   Function Example (Var Source, Dest; Count : Word) : Word; Assembler;
    var
     iAX, iBX, iCX, iDX, iBP, iSI, iDI, iSP: Word;
     iAH, iAL, iBH, iBL, iCH, iCL, iDH, iDL : Byte
    Asm
      Push  DS
      Mov   iBX, Count                              
      Mov   iAX, Word Ptr Dest
      Mov   iDI, iAX
      Mov   iAX, Word Ptr Dest+2
      Mov   iES, iAX 
.......
```

P.s
You might have to change "Push DS" and "POP DS" to "PUSH ESI" and "POP ESI"